# Unable to set row height equal to table height

Tags: html, css

Take a look at this Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/rahul_singh1/472532y8/1/

```
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <table class="top">
            <tbody>
                <tr><td>Text</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.main {height:40px; background-color:blue}
.top {height: 100%; width: 55%; margin: 0px auto 0px auto; background-color:green;}
.top>tbody>tr {height: 100%;}
.top>tbody>tr>td {color:red;background-color: white;}
```

I checked in the DOM. The `div`, `table` and `tbody` all have height = `40px`. But the row height is coming as `36px`.

how do I get the row height to be `100%`?

Comment: border-collapse:collapse maybe ? https://jsfiddle.net/472532y8/2/

Comment: Yup

putting 'border-collapse:collapse' property at the table worked perfectly fine. 

Thanks a lot.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply cellpadding and cellspacing to zero for your table.

```
<body>
<div class="main">
    <table class="top" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>Text</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/472532y8/3/)

You can achieve the same above using CSS also. Apply `padding:0; border-collapse:collapse;`

```
.top {height: 100%; width: 55%; margin: 0px auto 0px auto; padding:0; border-collapse:collapse; background-color:green;}
```

[**DEMO2**](https://jsfiddle.net/472532y8/4/)

Comment: or border-collapse in css to avoid extra attributes in html ... https://jsfiddle.net/472532y8/2/